# AudioSource play/PlayOneShot not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this code in OnStart

```
 void Start () {
     Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioListener> ().enabled = false;
     GameObject sfx_go = new GameObject();
     sfx_go.name = "sfx_go";
     sfx_player = sfx_go.AddComponent<AudioSource> ();
     sfx_go.AddComponent<AudioListener> ();
     clip = (AudioClip)Resources.Load("Sounds/wind", typeof(AudioClip)); 
     sfx_player.clip = clip;
```

}

then

```
void Update () {         
                     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                         //TODO play sound

                         sfx_player.PlayOneShot(clip, 0.7F);         
         }
```

my file is a wav file and playing in unity , but not from code. what is the probleme here? It looks like the AudioClip is Nothing in the unity editor

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sound file needs to be in a folder called "Resources" within the assets folder. Currently, Unity is looking for "Assets/Resources/Sounds/wind" as a filepath for your file. If your file is simply in "Assets/Sounds/wind" then it is in the wrong place.